# Obtain High Resolution Graphics suitable to Print

Tags: carto, export, printing

I have created a map with a single layer that needs to be exported for printing (30 dpi quality and quite large). I researched this extensively and see that the ability to export an image has been deprecated in the new Carto Builder UI. How should I proceed with getting this exported?

Comment: What program do you use? https://carto.com/builder/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean 300dpi...

If you're data lives in CARTO and you want to print high quality vector graphics, I suggest using the QGIS plugin offered from CARTO:

https://carto.com/blog/qgis-plugin

This will require you to do some re-styling of your data, but you should find  similar styling methods in QGIS as in CARTO

Then you can create a print composer at the correct size you want to print, orient your map, and run off some PDF's to see how the linework comes out at the scale you're plotting.